When using the printf function it ignores the variable and print "-858993460"
I'm working on an exercises on using the % operator and printing the number of biljets used in a random number of money.
So I start with asking the user for a number and then that number is converted to the different biljets and coins.
The problem is when I print it the last variable that is called in the printf function gives "-858993460" instead of 1. If I check in the memory of that variable it does contain 1. Can someone help me with this?
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int totaalGeld, briefjes500, briefjes200, briefjes100, briefjes50, briefjes20, briefjes10, briefjes5, munten2, munten1, rest;

    printf("Geef een hoeveelheid geld: ");
    scanf("%d%*c", &totaalGeld);
    briefjes500 = totaalGeld / 500;
    rest = totaalGeld % 500;
    briefjes200 = rest / 200;
    rest = rest % 200;
    briefjes100 = rest / 100;
    rest = rest % 100;
    briefjes50 = rest / 50;
    rest = rest % 50;
    briefjes20 = rest / 20;
    rest = rest % 20;
    briefjes10 = rest / 10;
    rest = rest % 10;
    briefjes5 = rest / 5;
    rest = rest % 5;
    munten2 = rest / 2;
    munten1 = rest % 2;
    printf("#briefjes van 500 euro: %d\n#briefjes van 200 euro: %d\n#briefjes van 100 euro: %d\n#briefjes van 50 euro: %d\n#briefjes van 20 euro: %d\n#briefjes van 10 euro: %d\n#briefjes van 10 euro: %d\n#briefjes van 5 euro: %d\n#munten van 2 euro: %d\n#munten van 1 euro: %d\n", briefjes500, briefjes200, briefjes100, briefjes50, briefjes20, briefjes10, briefjes5, munten2, munten1);

    return 0;
}

When I split up the printf in 2 different printf functions then it still happens but now it is at the end of the first printf function.
I expect the number that is inside the memory of the variable instead of "-858993460"

You appear to have written briefjes van 10 euro: %d twice.

Maybe the error would have been easier to spot if you didn't create a line that 100s of characters long!

You should always compile your code with warnings enabled, e.g. with -Wall if you're using GCC. When you do that - your compiler will often tell you what's wrong with the program...
In your case (GodBolt.org):
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:26:276: warning: format '%d' expects a matching 'int' argument [-Wformat=]
   26 |     printf("#briefjes van 500 euro: %d\n#briefjes van 200 euro: %d\n#briefjes van 100 euro: %d\n#briefjes van 50 euro: %d\n#briefjes van 20 euro: %d\n#briefjes van 10 euro: %d\n#briefjes van 10 euro: %d\n#briefjes van 5 euro: %d\n#munten van 2 euro: %d\n#munten van 1 euro: %d\n", briefjes500, briefjes200, briefjes100, briefjes50, briefjes20, briefjes10, briefjes5, munten2, munten1);
      |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ~^
      |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
      |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    int

so, like @user2357112 noted - you have more format specifiers than arguments following the format string.
Consider using shorter printf() statements - one for each line in your case. That reduces the chance of format-string<->argument mismatch.
PS - "biljets" are called "notes" or "banknotes" in English :-)
